# JavaFX - Giving a class access to a controller method to draw on a canvas

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx

I have the following files in my project:

- **main.java** for starting up the application
- **RootLayout.fxml** & **RootlayoutController.java** which serves as the main stage and will be used for a menu bar
- **Overview.fxm**l and **OverviewController.java** for the main window of the application
- **point.java** which contains the application logic

The OverviewController's test()-method is triggered by a Button's onAction-Event.
Essentially I am looking for a way to give the **Point.java** class access to the **OverviewController.java** class, so it can call the associated *drawPoint(double x, double y)* method.

I have been researching this question for quite a while now, but have been unable to find an understandable answer - since my knowledge of JavaFX is somewhat limited.

My sincere thanks for taking your time to answer my question.

Main.java

```
    public class Main extends Application {

    public Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    public Main(){

    }




    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

            this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
            this.primaryStage.setTitle("");
            initRootLayout();
            showOverview();

    }

    public void initRootLayout(){
        try {

            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class
                    .getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setHeight(900);
            primaryStage.setWidth(900);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);

            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public void showOverview(){
        try {

            // Load Overview
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/Overview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane overview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(overview);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            OverviewController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

OverviewController.java

```
   public class OverviewController {

       private sample.Main Main;

       public void setMainApp(Main mainApp) {
           this.Main = mainApp;
       }

       @FXML
       Canvas canvas;

       public void test(){
         Point point = new Point(5,5);
         point.drawPoint();
       }

       public void draw(double x, double y){

         GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
         gc.setFill(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
         gc.fillOval(x-4, y-4, 8, 8);

       }
 }
```

Point.java

```
public class Point {

    public double x;
    public double y;

    point(double x, double y){      
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;      
    }
    drawPoint(){
      // This is where I want to build a reference to OverviewController.java's draw(double x, double y)-Method
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a Model-View-Controller (or similar pattern) approach, instead of trying to let the data type `Point` have access to the controller class.

That way you can let any controller that has access to the model generate points. Your `OverviewController` just has to observe the model (or specific properties it contains) in order to draw the points onto the canvas, etc.

Create a model class:

```
public class Model {

    private final ObservableList<Point> points = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<Point> getPoints() {
        return points ;
    }

    // other data you need to share...

}
```

Then create an instance and give a reference to that instance to both your controllers:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    private final Model model ;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

            this.model = new Model();

            this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
            this.primaryStage.setTitle("");
            initRootLayout();
            showOverview();

    }

    public void initRootLayout(){
        try {

            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class
                    .getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setHeight(900);
            primaryStage.setWidth(900);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();

            // do you really need your controllers to have access to the main app?
            // it seems like it creates excessive coupling (you can no longer
            // use this fxml-controller pair anywhere else as it has a 
            // dependency on this application class)
            controller.setMainApp(this);

            controller.initModel(model);

            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public void showOverview(){
        try {

            // Load Overview
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/Overview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane overview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(overview);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            // WHY???

            OverviewController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);

            controller.initModel(model);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And now you can do:

```
public class OverviewController {

       private Model model ;

       public void initModel(Model model) {
           this.model = model ;
           this.model.getPoints().addListener((Change<? extends Point> change) -> {
               while (change.next()) {
                   if (change.wasAdded()) {
                       for (Point p : change.getAddedSublist()) {
                           draw(p.x, p.y);
                       }
                   }
               }
           });
       }

       @FXML
       Canvas canvas;

       public void test(){
         Point point = new Point(5,5);
         model.getPoints().add(point);
       }

       public void draw(double x, double y){

         GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
         gc.setFill(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
         gc.fillOval(x-4, y-4, 8, 8);

       }
 }
```

And similarly:

```
public class RootLayoutController {

    private Model model ;

    public void initModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model ;
    }

    // handler that adds a point:
    @FXML
    private void addPoint(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
        model.getPoints().add(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx/, which is very similar

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it really helped guiding me in the right direction. I have wondered how the implementation would change, if I would like to listen not only Objects which are added or removed from the _ObservableList<Point> point_, but also for changes in their property but I may have found the (your) answer already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313756/implementing-an-observablevalue I will also try to research the various hints you gave me in the source code. The link you attached has also helped me in gaining a better understanding of MVC.